# How to convert DateTime to Date

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

How can I convert `Date` to `DateTime` and vice versa?

E.g.

```
Date dt = new Date();
```

Now I want to covert this to `DateTime`.

Also

```
DateTime dtim = new DateTime();
```

Now I want to convert it to Date.

Answer (score 45):

Is this `Joda Time`'s `DateTime` you're talking about? If so, it will be

```
dateTime.toDate()
```

Answer (score 1):

As skaffman said above

```
dateTime.toDate()
```

should do the trick. But keep in mind that if the dateTime object had a different timezone than the user's current timezone, dateTime.toDate() will return the date object in user's timezone. 
ie

```
DateTime newDate = new DateTime().toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("America/Los_Angeles"));
System.out.println(newDate);
System.out.println(newDate.toDate());
```

This will print

2017-07-05T14:19:23.294-07:00

Wed Jul 05 15:19:23 MDT 2017

as my system time is in MDT

Answer (score 0):

I guess you convert it to UTC via Date.getTime(). And after that, use a constructor/setter on the other object.

Answer (score 0):

Transform to `date`:

```
dateTime.toDate()
```

Transform to `DateTime`:

```
new DateTime(new Date())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a DateTime to Date without losing the timezone, convert DateTime to Joda LocalDateTime first.

```
DateTime dateTimeUtc = new DateTime(); //because my default timezone is UTC
DateTime dateTimeBerlin = dateTimeUtc.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Berlin"));
Date convertedDate = dateTimeBerlin.toLocalDateTime().toDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way, would be to use the built-in `toDate()` method, like:

```
Date dt = new Date(); 
DateTime datetime = New DateTime(dt);

Date result = dateTime.toDate();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can easily use the [`toDate()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant.html#toDate%28%29) function which gets the date time as a `java.util.Date`:

```
Date date = MydateTime.toDate();
```