# Cannot resolve method "toDate()"

Tags: java, android, date, datetime

I am referencing to this question
[How to convert DateTime to Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005596/how-to-convert-datetime-to-date)

But I get the following error:

> Cannot resolve method "toDate()"

This is my code:

```
 DateTime startTime = event.getStart().getDateTime();

 Date startTimes = startTime.toDate();
```

And there are the packages I utilize:

```
import com.google.api.client.util.DateTime;
import java.util.Date;
```

Note that this is a google calendar api application for android.

My real goal is change the format of `startTime` using this code:

```
  String StartdateTxt = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
                        DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.SHORT).format(startTime);
```

Comment: They're talking about jodatime (a different lib) if you're referring to the question linked above, though I'm not sure you're not using jodatime yourself. If you weren't then that answers the question pretty simply, there isn't a #toDate. Why do you need the Date specifically, and why would a DateTime not work for you?

Comment: @Rogue I want to change the format of starttime to this:   SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`com.google.api.client.util.DateTime` doesn't have `toDate()` method. In you question you give us a link to another class which have same name from `Joda` libraries.

According to [docs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/util/DateTime) you can use `getValue()` method, to get epoch millis and then construct `Date` object:

```
DateTime startTime = event.getStart().getDateTime();
final Date startTimes = new Date(startTime.getValue());
```

Comment: Yes, that what I needed